# Filter out lines from input file

Tags: ansible

I am trying to read a file with some `key=value` data. I am able to do it using file lookup feature of ansible. Now the problem is I want to exclude the comments from the input file.But not sure how to do it. How to negate '`^#`' (line starting with `#`). I tried using  this command `{{ input_parms.split("\n")|regex_search('^[^#]') }}` but it did not worked as expected.

This is my input file

```
->cat mydata.cfg
#parms
name: 'foo'
place: 'bar'
id: 1
```

My playbook:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    parm_file: 'mydata.cfg'
    input_parms: "{{ lookup('file', parm_file) }}"
  tasks:
    - debug: var=input_parms.split("\n")
```

Current output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "input_parms.split(\"\n\")": [
        "#parms",
        "name: 'foo'",
        "place: 'bar'",
        "id: 1"
    ]
}
```

My expected output, without the commented line(`#parms`):

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "input_parms.split(\"\n\")": [
        "name: 'foo'",
        "place: 'bar'",
        "id: 1"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `select` and the `match` filter to select only lines that don't begin with `#`:

```
    - debug:
        var: input_parms.splitlines()|select('match', '^[^#]')|list
```

Which produces:

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "input_parms.splitlines()|select('match', '^[^#]')|list": [
        "name: 'foo'",
        "place: 'bar'",
        "id: 1"
    ]
}
```